# Matlab - specify colors for lines in parallelcoords

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I need to specify different colors in parallelcoords, but matlab chooses colors itself. How can I change it?

In documentation there is an example:

```
% Make a grouped plot of the raw data
load fisheriris
labels = {'Sepal Length','Sepal Width',...
          'Petal Length','Petal Width'};
parallelcoords(meas,'group',species,'labels',labels);
```

It uses default colors. But what if I want to specify different colors (for every group), where could I do that?

Comment: There is `parallelcoords(meas,'group',species,'labels',labels,'Color',c);`, but I can't find out the right format for c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
h=figure(1);
set(h,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 1 0;0 1 1;0 0 1]);

load fisheriris
labels = {'Sepal Length','Sepal Width',...
          'Petal Length','Petal Width'};
parallelcoords(meas,'group',species,'labels',labels);
```

Ref: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-the-color-of-lines-for-plotting.html